# control reaches end of non-void function c

Tags: c

I am getting this error even though my function is void? I thought the error only happens to non-void functions. Thanks in advance.

```
void scramble(void)
{
 char newgrid[DIMENSION][DIMENSION];
  for(int i=0; i<DIMENSION; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<DIMENSION; j++){
      newgrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
    }
  }
  for(int i = DIMENSION-1; i>=0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j<DIMENSION; i++){
      printf("%c", newgrid[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What error, I don't see any ??

Comment: What is this "edx" tag? The register `edx`?

Comment: I'm skeptical whether you're actually getting this error.

Comment: edx is an online platform by MIT and Harvard. www.edxonline.org

Comment: A wiki summary for that tag would be appreciated. Anyway, I can't reproduce the error, are you sure about that?

Comment: Nvm... Dumb error on my part. (put wrong section of code up. fixed it(it was void *)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i = DIMENSION-1; i>=0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j<DIMENSION; i++){
      printf("%c", newgrid[i][j]);
```

in the inner "for" loop, shouldn't that be j++? You've made an infinite loop.

Comment: It says control reaches end of non-void function. I think it may be a bug in the environment (It is custom made for the class).